# Object browsing and "array" properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I got a problem with one of my application today. With Ajax I get an object which is perfectly filled with the wanted values (checked with `console.log`). In this object each property is an array containing several numbers.

In my app I'm trying to browse through this object in order to get each array and do some stuff with it. The problem here is that I can't get back the array. In fact when using `for(var p in myObject)` it only get the property's name and not the value linked to it.

Here is a very tiny jsFiddle made to expose what I want to do : https://jsfiddle.net/rxj10cyk/
When using this code the console is logging plenty of string values but no array.

I think this have a link with the for..in loop, which I guess loop on properties names, but how can I obtain what I want ?

Comment: Your understanding about `for...in` is not proper. `For...in` will give you property name and to access value, you will have to use `object[k]`

Comment: Oh, right ! Thank you for the short delay of your answer ! That was a silly question, sorry.

Comment: your objects are illegal replace the "=" with ":"

Comment: Mistake is only in the fiddle, written very quickly with few attention, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the values of the key you need to use it like `myObject[data]`

Also note the `:` instead of `=` in object

```
var myObject = {
        first : [0,13,41,9],
      second : [33,6],
      third : [1,1,23]
    }

for(var data in myObject){
    console.log("data is "+data+" value is " +myObject[data]);
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/rxj10cyk/1/)

Answer (score 0):

[`for ( var p in myObject )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) will get the keys of the object; you need to then get `myObject[p]` to get the associated value with each key.

```js
var myObject = {
  first:  [0,13,41,9],
  second: [33,6],
  third:  [1,1,23]
}

for ( var key in myObject )
{
  var value = myObject[key];
  console.log( key );
  console.log( value );
}
```

or you can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array of the keys:

```js
var myObject = {
  first:  [0,13,41,9],
  second: [33,6],
  third:  [1,1,23]
}

var keys = Object.keys( myObject );
for ( var i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i )
{
  var value = myObject[keys[i]];
  console.log( keys[i] );
  console.log( value );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The for...in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, in arbitrary order.

```js
var myObject = {
  first: [0, 13, 41, 9],
  second: [33, 6],
  third: [1, 1, 23]
}

for (var key in myObject) {
  console.log(key, myObject[key]);
}
```

If you are using ES6, you can try `for...of`.

**Note:** For some reason I was not able to use it over `Object` but to loop over `Array` it works fine.

Following is a sample:

```js
var myObject = {
  first: [0, 13, 41, 9],
  second: [33, 6],
  third: [1, 1, 23]
}

for (val of myObject.first) {
  console.log(val);
}
```